# Is there any in-built Linux command to display the contents of a directory in real-time?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there any in-built Linux command to display the contents of a directory in real-time?Similar to the "tail -f file_name"  command which displays the contents of a file in real-time.

Comment: How about `watch -n1 ls`

Comment: Have a look at watch (http://www.linfo.org/watch.html)

Comment: Not quite built-in, but the `inotifytools` package uses Linux's `inotify` feature to allow watching file creation events as they happen.

Answer (score 8):

you can do this using `watch`. It is not completely real-time, but close enough (up to a tenth of a second):

```
watch -n0.1 ls
```

from the manual:

```
-n, --interval seconds
          Specify update interval.  The command will not allow quicker than 0.1 second interval, in which the smaller values are converted.
```

Comment: If you want to see new files more clearly, use `ls -lt` to see new files at the top of the listing or `ls -ltr` to see new files at the bottom. Then, to highlight those new files, use `watch -d` to highlight changes in the latest update or `watch --differences=cumulative` to highlight all the changes since `watch` was started.

Comment: @jm666 - `watch tail ls` or `watch head ls` will show the latest files with the correct **ls** ordering options, such as **-lt** with **head** or **-ltr** with **tail**.

Comment: @jm666 - Of course it's nonsense if taken literally: I was using it as a shorthand for `watch {options} 'ls {options} | tail {options}'`

Comment: @jm666: The request was for a command that follows changes to a directory as `tail -f` follows changes to file. Your original command was that `watch` didn't do that very well. I think it will, if the command it runs is crafted appropriately. Sometimes you have to use `sh -c` to wrap a more complicated command. I looked at inotify-tools briefly and did not see a command that would show the changes to a directory, not just the events applied to a directory.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this, I hope this is what you needed. It's not a `built-in Linux command`, but it uses only common programs present in most UNIX boxes.

Adjust `sleep` time as needed. I would use a value of at least 2 seconds.
Use `cmd="ls"` for non-recursive structure or `cmd="find DIRNAME"` to search recursively. Note that in the last case, you will get a `DIRNAME/` prefix to all files and directories.

```
 echo "" | awk '{while ( 1 ) {cmd="find ."; delete b;c=0; while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {test=1;c++;n=0;for (i in a) {n++;if (a[i]==result) {b[c]=i; test=0; break;}} if (test) {n++;a[n]=result;b[c]=n;print "##NEW## "result }} close (cmd); for (i in a) {test=1;for (j in b) {if (b[j]==i) {test=0;break}} if (test) {print "##DELETED## "a[i]; delete a[i]}} system("sleep 5") } }'
```

Comment: Found a bug that made `i` lost value after doing a loop that made the script show everything as new each time on some linux machines

Answer (score 1):

This is so simple after I know it.

```
watch -d dir_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inotifytools` and its command-line utilities.

You can use `inotify` to monitor directory, and it'll return events for the directory itself, and for files inside the directory.

Another tool which can be used is [`inotifywatch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch):

```
sudo inotifywatch -v -r /foo
```

You can add `-r` for to watch all subdirectories recursively. However this solution [doesn't detect changes on newly created files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164794/21471).

So another solution is to use `inotifywait`:

```
inotifywait -m --format "%f" /foo
```

Here is another example of showing content of all newly created `test*` files in `/tmp`:

```
inotifywait -m --format "%f" /tmp | grep --line-buffered ^test | xargs -L1 -I% sudo cat /tmp/% 2> /dev/null
```